# How to make jquery toggle work

Tags: jquery, html, click, toggle, slide

I have a simple two divs:

```
<div id="slide_menu">
<div id="tic">MENU</div>
</div>
```

And I would like to on click on div#tic to div#slide_menu toggle up and down.
I was trying to use slideUp and slideDown functions and also slideToggle. bot nothing work. Here is my latest jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tic').click(function () {
$('#slide_menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Anyone? Help?

Comment: If slide_menu is the parent, this would only work once because it hides the toggle div.

Also, put that in the document.ready jquery callback like this `$(document).ready(function(){ // your stuff });`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst The `#tic` element could be absolutely positioned...

Comment: That doesn't matter, if the parent is hidden so are the child elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a div inside and hide it before. when you click on the menu then toggleSlide that div.

```
<div id="slide_menu">
<div id="tic">MENU</div>
    <div class="expandMenu"></div>
</div>​


$('#tic').click(function () {
$('.expandMenu').slideToggle();
});​
```

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akdRk/)